# Why does the linear SVM give a lot of support vectors?

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I simulate a simple linear setup:

```
n = 1000
X = runif(n)
Y = runif(n)

ind = X + 2*Y < 1
ind[ind == TRUE] = runif(sum(ind)) < 1
plot(X,Y,col = ind + 1)
```

Which gives

[image: linear split]

The `svm()` functcion from `e1071` performs very well but it gives me a lot of vectors.

```
Call:
svm(formula = ind ~ X + Y, type = "C-classification", kernel = "linear")

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  linear 
       cost:  1 

Number of Support Vectors:  99
```

Can you please tell me what and how should I tune to get one vector (or just a few)?

Comment: Increase the value of the `cost` parameter to have less support vectors. If the kernel you use is linear, `gamma` is not used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! `gamma` was there from my another tests, I will update the code.

Comment: It would be fun to use cross validation to see what is the optimal value for this cost parameter !

Comment: For sure. In fact in the `e1071` package there is a `tune.svm` procedure, which takes a given set of parameters and does CV automatically, but this is a bit different story. Thanks for helping with this one :)

Comment: In my experience, tuning the regularisation parameter using CV generally results in models with lots of support vectors.  I would view the sparsity of SVM as a convenient by-product, but nothing more.  If you really want a sparse model, try something like L1 regularised logistic regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any linear SVM can be summarized as a single vector in input space:

$$f(\mathbf{z}) = \sum_{i \in SV} y_i \alpha_i \mathbf{x}_i^T\mathbf{z} +b,$$

can be rewritten as:

$$f(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{z}  + b,$$

with

$$w[k] = \sum_{i\in SV} y_i \alpha_i x_i[k], \quad k=1..d$$

The amount of support vectors that actually form the model is not that relevant for a linear SVM, except for prediction speed (the above comment applies).

The problem here is that e1071 apparently uses LIBSVM instead of LIBLINEAR for linear SVM's. LIBSVM doesn't turn a linear model into a single vector in input space.